# sql json formatting and summing

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

Basically I have a function which is returning me the json data from the database in this format:

```
"meanings": [
    "[
    {\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"product_id\": \"1\", \"quantity\": 4},
    {\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"product_id\": \"1\", \"quantity\": 1},
    {\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"product_id\": \"1\", \"quantity\": 1},
    {\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"product_id\": \"1\", \"quantity\": 4},
    {\"name\": \"Product 2\", \"product_id\": \"2\", \"quantity\": 4},
    {\"name\": \"Product 3\", \"product_id\": \"3\", \"quantity\": 4},
    {\"na]"
]
```

What I want to achieve is to sum quantity of all products with the same brand id and get the following result:

```
"meanings": [
    "[
    {\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"product_id\": \"1\", \"quantity\": 10},
    {\"name\": \"Product 2\", \"product_id\": \"2\", \"quantity\": 4},
    {\"name\": \"Product 3\", \"product_id\": \"3\", \"quantity\": 4},
    {\"na]"
]
```

I achieved that by writing the following, which is pure php, it does what I want but the problem is that this is API.
Calling this lots of times is not the best thing to do, and it will eventually start making problems.

```
$data = [];
$pId = [];
$objects = $this->reports()->getBasicMeans($this->id)->get();
foreach($objects as $object)
{
    $newData = json_decode($object);
    $data[$newData->product_id]['name'] = $newData->name;
    $data[$newData->product_id]['product_id'] = $newData->product_id;
    if (!in_array($newData->product_id, $pId)) {
        $pId[] = $newData->product_id;
        $data[$newData->product_id]['quantity'] = $newData->quantity;
    } else {
        $data[$newData->product_id]['quantity'] += $newData->quantity;
    }
}

$json['meanings'] = json_encode($data);
```

This is the query which is returning me the json. Would there be a way to modify the query which will get the results I want without using php functions to achieve that?

```
/**
 * Get basic means for the specified object.
 *
 * @param [type] $query
 * @param [type] $object
 * @return void
 */
public function scopegetBasicMeans($query, $object = null)
{
    $query->where('object_id', $object)->where('type', 1)
        ->join('report_asset', 'report_asset.report_id', '=', 'reports.id')->select(
            DB::raw(
                'SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(report_asset.resources, "$.quantity")) as amount'
            )
        )->groupBy(DB::raw('JSON_EXTRACT(report_asset.resources, "$.name")'));
}
```

I'm using mysql 5.7

QUERY:

```
select SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(report_asset.resources, \"$.quantity\")) as amount from `reports` inner join `report_asset` on `report_asset`.`report_id` = `reports`.`id` where `reports`.`object_id` = ? and `reports`.`object_id` is not null and `object_id` = ? and `type` = ? and `reports`.`deleted_at` is null group by JSON_EXTRACT(report_asset.resources, \"$.name\")
```

Comment: You could SUM(quantity) and GROUP BY name and get what you want directly from the query.

Comment: I have tried the following, see updated query, and i get null as amount.

Comment: Hi, can you dump the query generated by your code please ? And just to be sure: your $object is an identifier ? because you're using it as a value for object_id ... ?

Comment: Yes, $object is an identifier because I want records for specific objects. I edited the question with query.

Comment: If you need to do these kinds of calculations often, you are probably better off normalizing your database and not storing these records as json in one field.

Comment: Not often, only this api.